# Odd calculator bug (WPF Application)

Tags: c#, wpf

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="rekenmachine_variant_true.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rekenmachine_variant_true"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="118*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="683*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="1" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num1" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="72"/>
        <Button Content="2" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num2" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="72" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Content="3" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num3" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="72" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="4" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num4" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="72"/>
        <Button Content="5" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num5" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="72" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Content="6" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num6" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="7" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" Name="num7" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New"/>
        <Button Content="8" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" x:Name="num8" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Content="9" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" x:Name="num9" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="0" Click="num_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" x:Name="num0" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" FontStyle="Normal" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Button Content="." Click="decimal_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" x:Name="Nul_Copy" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" FontStyle="Normal" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="*" Click="keer_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,333,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80"  FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="/" Click="deel_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="483,333,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="=" Click="is_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="575,332,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="80" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" FontStyle="Normal" Grid.Column="1"   />
        <Button Content="+" Click="plus_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="-" Click="minus_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="483,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="80" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="%" Click="modulo_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="392,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="263"  FontSize="72" FontFamily="Courier New" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Button Content="CE" Click="clear_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="80" Width="80" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed" Background="#FFFFE74E" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="minmax" Content="-/+" Click="minusPlus_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="575,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="80" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Courier New" FontStyle="Normal" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="TxtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,24,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="746" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="110" FontSize="72" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextAlignment="Right"/>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace rekenmachine_variant_true
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        decimal valueFirst;
        decimal valueSecond;

        char operators;

        private void decimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TxtBox.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                TxtBox.Text += '.';
            }
        }

        private void num_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            TxtBox.Text += btn.Content.ToString();
            valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
        }

        private void minusPlus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TxtBox.Text.Contains("-"))
            {
                TxtBox.Text = TxtBox.Text.Trim('-');
            }
            else
            {
                TxtBox.Text = "-" + TxtBox.Text;
            }
        }

        private void minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
            TxtBox.Clear();
            operators = '-';
        }

        private void plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
            TxtBox.Clear();
            operators = '+';
        }

        private void keer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
            TxtBox.Clear();
            operators = '*';
        }

        private void deel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
            TxtBox.Clear();
            operators = '/';
        }

        private void modulo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
            TxtBox.Clear();
            operators = '%';
        }

        private void is_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueSecond = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
            decimal result = 0;

            if(operators == '+')
            {
                result = valueFirst + valueSecond;
                TxtBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operators == '-')
            {
                result = valueFirst - valueSecond;
                TxtBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operators == '*')
            {
                result = valueFirst * valueSecond;
                TxtBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operators == '/')
            {
                result = valueFirst / valueSecond;
                TxtBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operators == '%')
            {
                result = valueFirst % valueSecond;
                TxtBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            if (TxtBox.Text == "0")
            {
                TxtBox.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TxtBox.Clear();
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: **I'm aware minPlus, modulo, & decimal don't work atm but I want to figure them by myself. (The clear button doesn't really clear values it just clears text within txtbox)

Problem: Everything related to button 2(Name: "num2") messes up the whole calculation and I can't wrap my head around why.
Is there something about decimals that messes it up?

Example:

2 + 6 = 12

2 - 6 results in blank

85 + 2 = 4

Changing content on the number 2 button doesn't seem to work at all, it keeps giving the same results as the examples above.

Comment: So does this happen only for the button having the Content set to 2?

Comment: @GabrielStancu Nope, it's just that button in particular. Changing it to any other number will result in the same ex: 3 + 6 = 12

Comment: And does any other button work correctly? For instance if you do 3+6, will it output 9? Will 4*7 output 28? What about 30/5, will it show 6?

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment. <Hint>[State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)</Hint>

Comment: @GabrielStancu Huh it actually doesn't, i thought that it was only the button 2 but it looks like my entire calculator is fucked up

Comment: @ZanyZilch Unfortunately I cannot solve it for you if the whole application does not work. I would advice you to set breakpoints inside all the methods, take them one by one, and make sure each key press actually sends the proper values (digits, operators) in your backend. The code seems a little hard to follow, so you could also simplify it. If you still can't manage it, I'll give it a try later when I'll have a little bit more time. Good luck!

Comment: In you num_Click event you only set valueFirst - so your operations are valueFirst+valueFirst & valueFirst-valueFirst where valueFirst is the second number you clicked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
    private void num_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        TxtBox.Text += btn.Content.ToString();
        valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);
    }
```

For the first entry it may be okay, but after an operator button has been pressed the content of TxtBox will be something like: `2+6`

Thus `valueFirst = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);` will have `decimal` trying to parse "2+6".

Try:

```
    private void num_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        TxtBox.Text += btn.Content.ToString();
        valueFirst = decimal.Parse(btn.Content.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: If you check the code for plus_Click you will find that it clears TxtBox. So when the second digit button is clicked TextBox only contains that value - so the is_Click event "_valueSecond = decimal.Parse(TxtBox.Text);_" is only parsing "6" in your example. The click on the 6 button has already set valueFirst to 6 - so the result of valueFirst+valueSecond is effectively valueFirst+valueFirst.

Comment: Also - your solution will always set valueFirst to the value of the last digit clicked - so if someone entered a multiple digit number - then TxtBox would display (for example) '123' but valueFirst would be set to 3.